# Typeclass for functions with different numbers of arguments

Tags: function, haskell, dsl, typeclass

In my simple Haskell DSL, I have the following functions to call other functions:

```
callF :: forall a. (Typeable a)
  => (V a) -> (V a)
callF fp@(V (FunP name)) =
  pack $ FunAppl (prettyV fp) []

callF1 :: forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b)
  => (V (V a -> V b)) -> V a -> (V b)
callF1 fp@(V (FunP name)) arg =
  pack $ FunAppl (prettyV fp) [prettyV arg]

callF2 :: forall a b c. (Typeable a, Typeable b, Typeable c)
  => (V (V a -> V b -> V c)) -> V a -> V b -> (V c)
callF2 fp@(V (FunP name)) arg1 arg2 =
  pack $ FunAppl (prettyV fp) [prettyV arg1, prettyV arg2]
```

I would like to generalize this for any number of arguments using typeclasses.

This is what I've tried, but it only works for 0 or 1 arguments, and it doesn't enforce calling functions with the correct number of arguments.

```
class Callable a b | a -> b where
  call :: V a -> [String] -> b

instance Callable a (V b) where
  call fp@(V (FunP name)) x = pack $ FunAppl (prettyV fp) x

instance (Typeable c, Typeable d) => Callable (V a -> V b) (V c -> V d) where
  call fun@(V (FunP name)) list arg = call fun (list ++ [prettyV arg])
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `V a -> V b -> V c` is actually `V a -> (V b -> V c)`. You can do this through induction. Base case: `V a` is callable. Inductive case: given that `V a` is callable, then `V b -> V a` is callable. The instance head of the inductive case will have the general form `instance Callable k => Callable (m -> k) where`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The normal technique for functions with multiple arguments--like `printf`--is to use a recursive typeclass. For `printf`, this is done with a class called [`PrintfType`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Text-Printf.html#t:PrintfType). The important insight is the recursive instance:

```
(PrintfArg a, PrintfType r) => PrintfType (a -> r)
```

This basically says that if you can return a `PrintfType`, your function is *also* an instance. The "base case" is then a type like `String`. So, if you want to call `printf` with *one* argument, it fires two instances: `PrintfType String` and `PrintfType (a -> r)` where `r` is `String`. If you want *two* arguments, it goes: `String`, `(a -> r)` where `r` is `String` and `(a -> r)` where `r` is the previous `(a -> r)`.

However, your problem is actually a bit more complex. You want to have an instance that handles *two* different tasks. You want your instance to apply to functions of different types (e.g. `V (V a -> V b)`, `V (V a -> V b -> V c)` and so on) as well as ensuring that the right number of arguments is presented.

The first step to do this is to stop using `[String]` to pass in arguments. The `[String]` type loses information about how many values it has, so you can't check that there is an appropriate number of arguments. Instead, you should use a type for the argument lists that reflects how many arguments it has.

This type could look something like this:

```
data a :. b = a :. b
```

it is just a type for combining two other types, which can be used like this:

```
"foo" :. "bar"          :: String :. String
"foo" :. "bar" :. "baz" :: String :. String :. String
```

Now you just need to write a typeclass with a recursive instance that traverses both the type-level list of arguments and the function itself. Here's a very rough standalone sketch of what I mean; you'll have to adopt it to your particular problem yourself.

```
infixr 8 :.
data a :. b = a :. b

class Callable f a b | f -> a b where
  call :: V f -> a -> b

instance Callable rf ra (V rb) => Callable (String -> rf) (String :. ra) (V rb) where
  call (V f) (a :. rest) = call (V (f a)) rest

instance Callable String () (V String) where
  call (V f) () = V f
```

You will also have to enable a few extensions: `FlexibleInstances`, `FucntionalDepenedencies` and `UndecidableInstances`.

You could then use it like this:

```
*Main> call (V "foo") ()
V "foo"
*Main> call (V (\ x -> "foo " ++ x)) ("bar" :. ())
V "foo bar"
*Main> call (V (\ x y -> "foo " ++ x ++ y)) ("bar" :. " baz" :. ())
V "foo bar baz"
```

If you pass in the wrong number of arguments, you will get a type error. Admittedly, it's not the prettiest error message in the world! That said, the important part of the error (`` Couldn't match type `()' with `[Char] :. ()' ``) *does* point out the core problem (argument lists that don't match), which should be easy enough to follow.

```
*Main> call (V (\ x -> "foo " ++ x)) ("bar" :. "baz" :. ())

<interactive>:101:1:
    Couldn't match type `()' with `[Char] :. ()'
    When using functional dependencies to combine
      Callable String () (V String),
        arising from the dependency `f -> a b'
        in the instance declaration at /home/tikhon/Documents/so/call.hs:16:14
      Callable [Char] ([Char] :. ()) (V [Char]),
        arising from a use of `call' at <interactive>:101:1-4
    In the expression:
      call (V (\ x -> "foo " ++ x)) ("bar" :. "baz" :. ())
    In an equation for `it':
        it = call (V (\ x -> "foo " ++ x)) ("bar" :. "baz" :. ())
```

Note that this might be a bit over-complicated for your particular task--I'm not convinced it's the *best* solution to the problem. But it's a very good exercise in enforcing more complicated type-level invariants using some more advanced typeclass features.